# Streaming audio with ffmpeg library in C++/CLR, avcodec_fill_audio_frame returning -22 error code

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg

Good morning.
So I am working on a project where I need to stream realtime video & audio in C++ over an RTMP connection using FFmpeg's libraries. As far as I understand, the video & audio use two different streams so I am now trying to create an audio only stream.

MY PROBLEM: When calling FFmpeg's avcodec_fill_audio_frame() I receive an error code -22. This tells me nothing seeing as the FFmpeg library's documentation...leaves a great deal to be desired.

My MainForm.h has the following (relevant) members

```
private: NAudio::CoreAudioApi::MMDevice^ waveDevice_chat;
private: NAudio::Wave::WaveIn^ waveInput_chat;
private: NAudio::Wave::IWavePlayer^ waveOutput_chat;
private: NAudio::Wave::BufferedWaveProvider^ waveProvider_chat;
```

Fist step is to connect the mic:

```
System::Void MainForm::btnConnectMic_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    waveEnumerator_chat = gcnew NAudio::CoreAudioApi::MMDeviceEnumerator();
    System::Collections::Generic::List<NAudio::CoreAudioApi::MMDevice^>^ wavePorts_chat = System::Linq::Enumerable::ToList(waveEnumerator_chat->EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow::Capture, DeviceState::Active));

    if (wavePorts_chat->Count > 0) {
        waveDevice_chat = (NAudio::CoreAudioApi::MMDevice^)(wavePorts_chat[0]);
        waveDevice_chat->AudioEndpointVolume->Mute = false;

        waveInput_chat = gcnew WaveIn();
        waveInput_chat->BufferMilliseconds = 50;
        waveInput_chat->DeviceNumber = 0;
        waveInput_chat->WaveFormat = gcnew NAudio::Wave::WaveFormat(44100, 1);
        waveInput_chat->DataAvailable += gcnew System::EventHandler<NAudio::Wave::WaveInEventArgs ^>(this, &MainForm::waveInput_data_available);
        waveInput_chat->StartRecording();

        waveProvider_chat = gcnew BufferedWaveProvider(gcnew NAudio::Wave::WaveFormat(44100, 1));
        waveProvider_chat->DiscardOnBufferOverflow;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the EventHandler which is called by NAudio when data is available

```
void MainForm::waveInput_data_available(System::Object^ sender, WaveInEventArgs^ e) {
    if (waveProvider_chat->BufferedBytes + e->BytesRecorded > waveProvider_chat->BufferLength)
        waveProvider_chat->ClearBuffer();
    else
        waveProvider_chat->AddSamples(e->Buffer, 0, e->BytesRecorded);
}
```

And finally, here is the code snippet that is supposed to fill my audio frame (this is runnign in a loop in a background worker)

```
uint8_t* new_buffer;
int result
AVFrame* a_frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVStream* astrm;
AVCodec* acodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AVCodecID::AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);

/*
 *
 *
 *
 */

in the loop

    if (read_buffer->Length <= 0)
        continue;

    new_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc((size_t)waveProvider_chat->BufferedBytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < waveProvider_chat->BufferedBytes; i++)
        new_buffer[i] = (uint8_t)read_buffer[i];

    AVPacket a_pkt;
    av_init_packet(&a_pkt);
    a_pkt.data = nullptr;
    a_pkt.size = 0;
    int got_a_packet = 0;

    int a_encode = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(a_frame, astrm->codec->channels, astrm->codec->sample_fmt, new_buffer, read_buffer->Length, 0);
    std::cout << "[FILL] encoded response: " << a_encode << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the source code of [avcodec_fill_audio_frame](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/libavcodec_2utils_8c_source.html#l00470), you see

```
if (buf_size < needed_size)
    return AVERROR(EINVAL);
```

where `EINVAL` happens to be 22.

So in your case, I would guess, the buffer is not large enough.

Comment: Thank you! So what I think is happening is that NAudio keeps adding samples to it's buffer which has a size of 441000 and I keep reading everything in the current buffer. I have a few new ideas to try, will let you know